# Prevent 'lein repl' in SublimeREPL from echoing the previous command

Tags: clojure, sublimetext3, sublimetext, leiningen, sublimerepl

I'm running Sublime Text 3 Build 3117 on both OS X 10.10.5 and Ubuntu 16.04. I just installed Leiningen 2.6.1 on both, and I'm starting to play around in SublimeREPL. I'm following the [lein tutorial](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md). Here is my `project.clj`, in case it matters:

```
(defproject my-stuff "0.1.0"
  :description "Leiningen Tutorial Project"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "MIT"
            :url "http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot my-stuff.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}}
  :repl-options {
    ;; custom prompt
    prompt (fn [ns] (str "> " ))
  }
)
```

Now, when I run `lein repl` in the `my-stuff` directory from the command line and run an arbitrary command (I've been using `(+ 1 2 3)`), it prints out the answer nicely:

[image: lein repl from command line]

However, if I run `lein repl` from SublimeREPL with `project.clj` focused, and run the same command, it echoes the command before printing the return value:

[image: lein repl in SublimeREPL]

I've also created a `lein trampoline run -m clojure.main` command for SublimeREPL, and it doesn't have the echoing problem:

[image: lein trampoline]

Basically, what I would like to do is be able to run a REPL using `project.clj`, but not have every command echoed before the output is printed. I can't seem to figure out how to run a trampoline REPL in Sublime using `project.clj`, if that's the best option. If there's a different way, i.e., using `lein repl`, I just want to get rid of the command echo, and make it look similar to what appears when I run it from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to some [help](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/prevent-sublimerepl-clojure-repl-from-echoing-most-recent-command/21261/2) at the Sublime Text Forum, I got an answer: you simply need to put `"suppress_echo": true` in the `Main.sublime-menu` file where the Clojure menu options are defined. In this case, open `Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Clojure/Main.sublime-menu`, put a comma `,` after `"extend_env": {"INSIDE_EMACS": "1"}`, then on the next line put `"suppress_echo": true` and you're all set.